# Conseguir uma APN auth key da Apple

Tags: ssl, certificado-digital, apple-push-notification

To tentando usar o sistema de Push Notification da Apple, porém não consigo entrar na pagina "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles" na pagina de desenvolvedor deles, simplesmente não tem essa opção lá, não tem menus nem nada, só a pagina "Welcome", "Forum", "Reportar Bugs", etc..

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Sua conta é de desenvolvedor? você pagou os U$ 100?

Comment: Oloko, tem q pagar pra ter acesso à esses serviços? É uma conta de desenvolvedor sim, pelomenos eu logo no site de desenvolvedor deles.

Comment: Achei onde é, vlw cara

Comment: Mas pra poder ter acesso ao certificado, subir apps e etc, custa 100 dolares por ano